# SharePoint 2013 taking long time to recover after VS 2012 solution deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I am aware that when we deploy a solution from Visual Studio, there are lot of things going on under the hood and in SP 2010 we used to have a 5-6 second page load delay when we deployed something but this is not the case for SP 2013. Sometimes I had to wait for 3-4 minutes. Has anyone faced this problem before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling IntelliTrace in Visual Studio.  It should increase page performance after deployment.

Answer (score 1):

The deafult deployment config does an IISRESET when deploying a wsp and that will slow things down when requesting a page for the first time. I've noticed that dev environments that worked fine with SP2010 doesn't work that well with SP2013, primarily because it requires more RAM.

One thing you could try is to create a new Web app and and only associate the service apps necessary to support your custom solution with that Web app. Then deploy your wsp to a site collection in the new Web app. That way you can figure out if there's something related to your code that causes a slow down or if it's becuase the IISRESET unloads a lot of service apps and other "stuff" from the appdomains that then have to be re-loaded.